# Can't read cookies in Javascript when using IE11

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, cookies

I have an angular app and am using cookies to keep track of some information.  I access this cookie with javascript and everything works great on Chrome but when running IE11 and I step through the code the JS doesn't read the cookie.  I can see it on the developer tools and it is not set to HTTP only. I have already enabled all cookies on IE.

Any help would be appreciated since I have no clue why IE won't play nicely with my app.

Here is how I set the cookie on my controller

```
HttpResponseMessage Response = new HttpResponseMessage();
JsonMediaTypeFormatter json = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
Response.Content = new ObjectContent<PvUser>(MyPOCO, json, "application/json");
var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(cookieName, cookieValue);
cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(20);
cookie.HttpOnly = false;
Response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
```

This is the code from w3schools that I am using to read a cookie by name

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pain and suffering I still don't know why this is happening but found that this issue doesn't occur when I use HttpReponse instead of HttpResponseMessage.

```
HttpResponse Response =HttpContext.Current.Response;
Response.Clear();
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
Response.StatusCode = 200;// HttpStatusCode.OK;
Response.ContentType = "applicaiton/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(loggedInUser));
Response.End();
```